# Does bounded limits of one integral imply that the double integral is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I know that [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#) means that the one may switch the oder of integration if the double integral yields a finite value when the *integrand* is replaced by its absolute value.

But I have also heard that if one of the integrals has limits which are bounded, then the double integral is bounded, too:

Is the following true?

($|a|\ne\infty, and |b|\ne\infty$) or ($|c|\ne\infty, and |d|\ne\infty$)  $\implies$  $\int_{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{b}} \int_{\mathbf{c}}^{\mathbf{d}} |f(x)|<\infty$

But I don't think this is true, because the limits might be bounded, but the integrand could be something like the Dirac delta, in which cases the integration does not yield something finite...

Does bounded limits of one integral imply that the double integral is bounded?

Comment: Can you state your question more clearly using symbols?

Comment: Here is [an introduction to posting mathematical notation]().  When you refer to "limits" that "one of the integrals has", it is unclear whether you are thinking of the limits of integration (region over which the integral is taken) or *bounds* on the the integrand.  Your Question would be improved by introducing notation that will clarify your meaning.

Comment: I'm still new at this, but I did my best to modify the question let me know if it is better plaese